# Initializing 2 classes that have each other in their constructor

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes, **ExceptionHandler** and **Localizer**. The **ExceptionHandlers** `constructor` looks like this:

```
public ExceptionHandler(ILocalizer localizer, string logLocation)
{
    Localizer = localizer;
    LogLocation = logLocation;
}
```

Further in the class the `localizer` is used to localize certain exception messages like "File not found" in English, "Bestand niet gevonden" in Dutch, ...

On the other hand, the **Localizer** class can have certain exceptions and therefore needs the **ExceptionHandler** class. The constructor looks like this:

```
public Localizer(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler)
{
    ExceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
}
```

Now, is it me or is what I want impossible to achieve? Is there any workaround to get it to work?

Comment: Yes its impossible, indeed.

Comment: circular dependency.. must be kind of design overlook! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `Localizer.ExceptionHandler` after both `Localizer` and `ExceptionHandler` objects are created. Just make sure constructor does not throw exceptions, or the exceptions in the `Localizer` constructor are handled without `ExceptionHandler`

Comment: I guess it would also work the other way around? But is this really a "clean" solution or should I change my code design?

Comment: @Krowi I don't know if it's "clean", but based on provided info that's how I would do it. If I had more info, who knows, maybe I would completely redesign the code.

Comment: The plan is to initialize these 2 classes when the application starts. This way I have 2 "global" classes I can use anywhere in my application. (I tried DI but it's too confusing right now and has nothing to do with my problem afaik)